# How to convert epoch time to year

Tags: c++, c

I have time in epoch format.
I just want to retrieve Year from it.

how should we do it in c or c++ ?

Actually i have time since epoch in seconds and i need to calculate age depending on it.
So input will be seconds since epoch and out put should be Age based on current date.

Thanks,
PP.

Comment: sample data input and expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C timestamps (ie: seconds from epoch) are usually stored in `time_t`, while human-wise dates are stored in structure `tm`. You need a function that converts `time_t`s in `tm`s.

`gmtime` or `localtime` are two C standard function that do your job.

```
struct tm *date = gmtime( your_time );
printf( "Year = %d\n", date->tm_year );
```

Warning that these functions are not thread-safe. You'll find a reentrant version on POSIX systems (linux, mac os x, ...): `gmtime_r` and `localtime_r`

Comment: Note that the `tm_year` field is in years since 1900, so you need to add 1900 to that field to get the actual year.

Answer (score 7):

Using the `gmtime` or `localtime` functions to convert the `time_t` to a `struct tm`. Then you can use the `tm_year` field of the struct to get the year.

Or for offline use, you can use a web converter, [like this](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

**Edit:**

Sample code:

```
time_t nowEpoch = time(NULL);
struct tm* nowStruct = gmtime(&nowEpoch);
int year = nowStruct->tm_year + 1900;
```

Comment: can you post sample code for this, that will help more. Thanks.

Comment: A web converter for *offline* use?

Comment: @Donal, offline as in not in an application :)

Comment: “You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.”

Comment: @Donal, thanks, I know what it means. We use it here at work to differentiate between an online process/need (that needs to happen in the application itself) from an offline process/need (that can be done at our leisure). Of course the use of an online web page to perform an offline task is amusing.

Answer (score 3):

> Actually i have time since epoch in seconds and i need to calculate age depending on it.
>   So input will be seconds since epoch and out put should be Age based on current date.

You don't need the year, month, day of either timestamp for this.  Subtract the two epoch times to get a value in seconds.  Divide by 60*60*24*365 to [get a value in years](http://codepad.org/5o5FD9qt):

```
int main() {
  time_t past = 1234567890;
  time_t now = time(0);
  double years = double(now - past) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365;
  cout << "years = " << years << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

This will be off by any leap seconds that have occurred between the two timestamps, but, significantly, it gives the correct value *within* a year.  For example, 1 Dec. 2010 to 1 Jan. 2011 is approximately 1/12th of a year, not 1 year.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Not sure if the above folks read through the whole question.